# Laravel ajax cannot parse json?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I am building a live search and currently I have 3 problems.

Problem 1: JSON data is not displaying, error message is:

> Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in {"results":[{"id":1,"title":"Guardians of the Galaxy","times":"12:40","business_id":1,"date":"2017-06-19","created_at":"2017-06-19 08:15:30","updated_at":"2017-06-19 08:15:30"},

Problem 2: I am using keyup event however that is perfoming search on every character input, so if someone puts 5 characters, it does a LOT of requests.

Problem 3: Which is related to problem 2 probobly is that even when user stops typing in the browser for some reason it is still making requests and it never stops?

Here's my search box:

```
   <form id="cinema_display">
                    <div class="form-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search_cinemas" onkeyup="search_cinema(this.value);" placeholder="Search film">
                </div>
   </form>
                    <div id="show">

     </div>
```

AJAX:

```
function search_cinema(cinema_value) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/cinemasearch/' + cinema_value,
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
                var items = JSON.parse(data);
                var showElement = $('#show');
                showElement.html('');
                $.each(data, function() {
                   showElement.append(this.title +' '+ this.times+'<br />');
                });
        },
        error: function(data) {

        },
        headers: {
        'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }                 
    });
}
```

Controller:

```
    public function cinema_search($cinema_value) {
        if (empty($cinema_text)) {
            $data = Film::all();
        } else {
            $data = Film::where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$cinema_value.'%')->with('business')->get();
        }
        return response()->json(['results' => $data]);
    }
```

Someone please make my day happy, I spent on this a lot of time and still cannot make it to work :(

Comment: use `dataType: 'json',` instead of `dataType: 'html',`. what are you getting in JSON response?

Comment: Does the variable this have any value in this context?

Comment: If I do console.log(data) I get an array but when I try search it appends undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work :

```
function search_cinema(cinema_value) {
  if(cinema_value.length > 3)
   {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/cinemasearch/' + cinema_value,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
                //var items = JSON.parse(data);                    
                var html = '';
                $.each(data.results, function(index,item) {
                   html += item.title +' '+ item.times+'<br />';
                });

               $('#show').html(html);
        },
        error: function(data) {

        },
        headers: {
        'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }                 
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: this is great, any ideas why if I input 'e' it still brings me back 'Guardians of the Galaxy'? I don't think it contains 'e'

Comment: since u hv `%` i.e wildcard on both side of the string so if u type `e` it searches for any string with the letter `e`. 'Guardians of the Galaxy' it contains `e` in `the`

Comment: okay, how about my second problem? what would be a solution for that?

Comment: u can try serching in the db if the keyword greater then  3 or 4 character.
or u cn search onchange rather then onkeyup.

Comment: What's the different between those 2? In terms on how they work, and can you edit the code to include 1 of those option (the one you think will work better?) thanks

Comment: i hv updated the code , now it will search in the database only if keyword is greater then 3 character, by doing this u hv less request and more accurate result as 1 or 2 or 3 character matches almost everything, onkeyup feels more responsive.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147044/discussion-between-riaz-laskar-and-przemek).

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is here:

```
dataType: 'html',
```

change it to:

```
dataType: 'json',
```

and try again. As you are returning a json from controller like:

```
return response()->json(['results' => $data]);
```

Comment: I get: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1